# Nowheresville and other cities of renown

Tags: vocabulaire

Je viens d'écouter le musicien Steve Bell qui qualifie Marie mère de Jésus d'originaire de « Nowheresville » .

> [God comes to this insignificant nobody from Nowheresville...](https://unfamiliarplace.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/nowheresville.mp3)

Là, je réfléchis, on a un type de composé qui se fait souvent sur un coup de tête, et qui est quelque peu courant, employé de toute évidence dans le but de faire rire.

> You and everyone else in Loserville.
>
> Boring? Tell me about it! It was totally Dullsville.

Il y a une définition sur Urban Dictionary (#4 sur [cette liste](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ville) ; je n'arrive pas à trouver un lien direct) :

> Popular suffix attached to any word as an intensifier.
>
> *He's tiredville after lookin' for us around the whole town.*

Quel est l'équivalent français le plus proche ? J'imagine que l'on évitera « ville de » ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le premier cas, on a affaire a une dénomination désignant un "trou perdu" imaginaire. En France les termes les plus typiques sont *Perpète-les-Oies* ou *Trifouilly-les-Oies*. Au Québec, on entend souvent *Saint-Glinglin-les-Meuh-Meuh*. [Wikipedia a une liste.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trou_perdu)

Le second cas (différent du troisième, qui est une forme d'emphase au même titre que la formulation *[-ass](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ass)* dans *dumbass* ou *cheapass*) tient plutôt de la figure de style un peu figée plutôt que d'une expression spécifique (bien qu'elle ne me semble pas particulièrement fréquente). Rien n'interdit des formulations équivalente reprenant une construction "typique" en -ville ou autre construction fréquente pour une municipalité (Au Québec, ce serait en Saint-).

L'expression passerait probablement assez bien ("On se serait cru à Saint-Ennuyeux/Rasoirville"), même si la formulation n'est pas une expression établie.

Comment: Le trou perdu imaginaire classique est "Pétaouchnok". On retrouve d'alleurs sur Wiktionnaire une [liste de synonymes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/P%C3%A9taouchnok). Personnellement, j'utilise classiquement « Perpète-les-bains ».

Comment: Intéressant. Je dois essayer « Rasoirville » avec un ami pour voir sa réaction ... Ces noms de « trous perdus » partagent-ils une origine ? Pourquoi est-ce que beaucoup d'entre eux sont composés sur la base de « X-les-Y » ?

Comment: Interesting wikipedia article.  I think it's a bit too wide-ranging, but never mind.  A friend from the South East (Montpellier-Marseille) is very fond of Cuges-les-Bains, apparently derived from the real Cuges-les-Pins which is geographically close to Marseille but used to be very hard to get to.  As a Parisian, I grew up mostly with Trifouilly-les-Oies, which was re-interpreted more often as Perpete-les-Oies in Toulouse.